# Office365 Graph API - combining NOT filters

Tags: odata, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to perform a query using the Office 365 Graph API which uses multiple NOT filters, and I'm seeing some very strange behaviour.

Starting with a single NOT filter clause works fine:

```
/me/messages?$search="NOT from:joebloggs@outlook.com"
```

EDIT: Combining two NOT filters works as follows

```
/me/messages?$search="NOT from:joebloggs@outlook.com AND NOT to:joebloggs@outlook.com"
```

But combining **four** NOT filters doesn't work

```
/me/messages?$search="NOT from:joebloggs@outlook.com AND NOT to:joebloggs@outlook.com AND NOT cc:joebloggs@outlook.com AND NOT bcc:joebloggs@outlook.com"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I’ve tested the expression below at my side and it works.

> $search="NOT from:joebloggs@outlook.com AND NOT
> to:joebloggs@outlook.com"
>
> $search="NOT from:axx@mail.com AND NOT to:bxx@mail.com AND NOT cc:cxx@mail.com AND NOT bcc:dxx@mail.com"

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, that works for me too. But following that syntax I still can't get it to work for 4 NOTs i.e. NOT from AND NOT to AND NOT cc AND NOT bcc. Any ideas?

Comment: I will update the question to reflect this information

Comment: David, did you get any errors or the result is not expected? As I tested, the 4 NOTs also works.

Comment: No errors, but the result is not as expected. I think I may have tracked it down further with some additional test cases...

I experimented by removing some search terms and the queries behave as follows:

not to and not cc - CORRECT

not to and not from - INCORRECT

not cc and not from - INCORRECT
 
This suggests this is a problem with the NOT FROM filter. And interestingly, this doesn't work even on its own.
 
I think this may be the source of the bug. It would be great if you could try this on your end and see if you can reproduce the behaviour I've seen.

Comment: Just to clarify - this is the query which is not working: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="NOT from:joebloggs@outlook.com"